# How to extract just the "basename" of parent directory in shell?

Tags: shell, find, zsh, mv

I need to rename a couple of files using shell scripting, by a certain "key". This key includes both strings as well as extracted portions of file path that I get with `find`.

I am on a Mac, OSX El Capitan and am using ZSH. Here is the **directory tree**:

```
├── 300x250
│   ├── 300x250-img-fallback.jpg
│   └── index/
├── 300x600
│   ├── 300x600-img-fallback.jpg
│   └── index/
├── 336x280
│   ├── 336x280-img-fallback.jpg
│   └── index/
└── 970x250
    ├── 970x250-img-fallback.jpg
    └── index/
```

I need to rename **../index/** folders into **../c2_[parentFolderName]/**. This is what I am trying:

```
find . -type d -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -exec sh -c 'echo -- mv "$0" "$(dirname "$0")"/"C2_"$(basename "$0/..")""' {} \;
```

This doesn't seem to be the proper way to get the `basename` of the parent unfortunately.

```
find . -name "*index" -exec sh -c 'echo -- mv "$0" "$(dirname "$0")"/"C2_"$(basename "$0/..")""' {} \;
```

This one is just a variation which also does not work (there is no reason why it should :) ).

I am quite new to shell scripting and am trying to learn as much as possible in a *shell agnostic* kind of way, so please disregard that I am using ZSH currently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best would be to use `zsh`'s [`zmv`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv):

```
autoload zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
zmv -n '(*)/index' '$1/C2_$1'
```

(remove `-n` when happy).

For a portable ([POSIX `sh`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/xcu.html)) solution:

```
for dir in */index;  do
  mv -i -- "$dir" "${dir%/*}/C2_${dir%/*}"
done
```

(using `-i` as a poor man's ersatz to the sanity checks `zmv` does).

If you wanted to use [`find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) portably (POSIXly), you'd need to forget about `-mindepth`/`-maxdepth`, which you can replace with combinations of `-path` and `-prune`:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -path './*/*' -prune -name index -exec sh -c '
  for dir do
    top=${dir#./}
    top=${top%/*}
    mv -i -- "$dir" "$top/C2_$top"
  done' sh {} +
```

One difference with the other two approaches is that it will not follow symlinks and that it will also look for `index` in hidden directories.

Those make use of the standard `${var#pattern}`, `${var%pattern}` parameter expansion operators described in countless Q&As here or at the [POSIX shell specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02).

Comment: Stéphane, thank you for your reply! Since I'm new to this, care to explain a bit more? I "believe" that this finds everything (*) "here" with name "index" and replaces variable1 with a string_variable2. How come ot doesn't start with 0 like in bash?

Comment: @AlexStarbuck, `$0` is the programs/function name while `$1`..., `$n` are the positional parameters. I've added links to documentation. See also [Is there a reason why the first element of a Zsh array is indexed by 1 instead of 0?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/252368)

Comment: I was taught that when you use `{}` with say `find`, the results get automatically "ordered" into variables `$0`, `$1`, `$2`, ... Seems that there is much more to learn.

Comment: @AlexStartbuck, in `sh -c '...' a b c`, indeed `a` goes to `$0` and `b` to `$1`, but `$0` is interpreted as the _name_ of that inline script, not an argument to that inline script, just like when you run `sh myscript a b c`, `myscript` (this time not inline) gets `a`, `b`, `c` as _arguments_ (`"$@"`) and `myscript` in `$0`.  So you should give the _name_ that you want to give to that inline script as that first argument (I usually use `sh`). Where it matters is that that `$0` gets used in error messages. Try for instance: `sh -c 'echo > /' foo bar`

Comment: After running: `sh -c 'echo > /' foo bar`, as you suggested, I got this: `foo: /: Is a directory` :)

Comment: @AlexStartbuck, yes, exactly, see how the error message is reported as coming from a command called `foo`, as that's what ended up in `$0` (the inline script name).

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, your attempt

```
find . -type d  -exec sh -c 'echo -- mv "$0" "$(dirname "$0")"/"C2_"$(basename "$0/..")""' {} \;
```

seems to almost work, except that `basename` doesn't interpret the dot-dot. But taking `dirname` should give you the parent's name, and you can take the `basename` of that. Something like this:

```
$ mkdir -p 300x250/index 970x250/index
$ find . -name index -exec sh -c 'echo mv "$1" "$(dirname "$1")/C2_$(basename "$(dirname "$1")")"' sh {} \;
mv ./300x250/index ./300x250/C2_300x250
mv ./970x250/index ./970x250/C2_970x250
```

As Stéphane mentioned, the first argument after `sh -c "..."` is taken as the script's name, which goes in `$0` and is distinct from the usual positional parameters from `$1` upward. The latter have tools specifically to work with them, like `shift` and `$@`, and they don't work with `$0`.

For just one argument, using `$0` could work, but as the shell's name might be used for other purposes, it's preferable to set something sensible (like `sh`) there, and put the actual arguments after that.

Comment: Ilkkachu - how would you in that case get the grandparent's `basename`? Or further up the folder hierarchy?

Comment: `$0` is also used for error messages by the shell, so it's generally better to put something sensible in it like `sh` or `inline-sh`.  Using `-exec sh ... inline-sh {} +` and a loop in `sh` also avoids running one `sh` instance per file.

Comment: The `${file%/*}` operator has that extra benefit over `$(dirname -- "$file")` (beside the obvious performance one) that it also works if `$file` ends in newline characters.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas One shell per file?! :O I see. Unfortunately, this is as much as I can grasp now, without someone guiding me through your script step by step I am unlikely to lear correctly. Is there a way I can contact dou directly for a couple of messages?

Comment: @Alex, yes, `find -exec {} ;` runs the given command for every file separately. `-exec {} +` stacks multiple files to the command line of one invocation. And yes, the `for x in */index` approach is usually better than using `find` (for various reasons), and cutting the string with the shell's operations is faster than calling `basename` and `dirname`. I meant this only as a minimal fix to your original attempt, and frankly I'd prefer if you checked another answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Never worked on **ZSH**, but below code works very well on **bash**

```
SHW@SHW:/tmp/test1 # tree
.
├── 300x250
│   ├── 300x250-img-fallback.jpg
│   └── index
├── 300x600
│   ├── 300x600-img-fallback.jpg
│   └── index
├── 336x280
│   ├── 336x280-img-fallback.jpg
│   └── index
└── 970x250
    ├── 970x250-img-fallback.jpg
    └── index

8 directories, 4 files

SHW@SHW:/tmp/test1 # for i in `find . -type d -name index`; do  mv $i `dirname $i | cut -c3-`/c2_`dirname $i | cut -c3-`; done

SHW@SHW:/tmp/test1 # tree
.
├── 300x250
│   ├── 300x250-img-fallback.jpg
│   └── c2_300x250
├── 300x600
│   ├── 300x600-img-fallback.jpg
│   └── c2_300x600
├── 336x280
│   ├── 336x280-img-fallback.jpg
│   └── c2_336x280
└── 970x250
    ├── 970x250-img-fallback.jpg
    └── c2_970x250

8 directories, 4 files
```