# Converting integer to day-of-week using date(1)

Tags: shell, date

Using `date`, I can convert days of weeks to integers ranging from 1 to 7, for example:

```
$ date -d "Thursday" +%u
4
```

But what if I want to perform the reverse operation? Something like,

```
$ date [options] [+format]
Thursday
```

It's okay if it's not possible with date, I can use other programs as well. Aiming for brevity here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could get the date for next Sunday, add `N` days and print the day name for that particular date:

```
getdayname () {
nextplus=$(date -d "next Sunday +$1 days")
date -d "${nextplus}" '+%A'
}
```

and run `getdayname 2`, `getdayname 7` etc (assuming `gnu date`).
Or simply use an array and do without the `date` e.g.

```
getdayname () {
local days=( Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday )
printf %s\\n ${days[$1]}
}
```

though with `bash`/`ksh` you need `printf %s\\n "${days[$1-1]}"` (as indexing [starts at `0`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/252368)), and quotes are needed to avoid split+glob (also with `yash`).

Answer (score 2):

Based on don_crissti's answer, since his first answer gives me incorrect results:

```
getdayname() {
        date -d "$(( 7-$(date '+%u')+$1 )) days" '+%A'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

POSIXly (`-d` is not a standard `date` option. When available, it means something different to different implementations), to give the day name in the user's locale, Sunday being either 0 or 7:

```
getdayname() (
  IFS=';'
  set -o noglob
  days=$(locale day) || exit
  for day do
    set -- $days $days
    shift "$day" &&
      printf '%s\n' "$1"
  done
)
```

Examples:

```
$ getdayname 0 4 7
Sunday
Thursday
Sunday
$ LANG=es_VE.UTF-8 getdayname 0 4 7
domingo
jueves
domingo
```

With GNU or busybox `date` (whose `-d ...` doesn't support relative dates), or ast-open `date` (whose `-d ...` supports relative dates but in a different way from GNU's `date`):

```
getdayname() (
  for day do
    date -ud "1970-01-$((day + 11))" +%A
  done
)
```

With `zsh` without external requirements:

```
$ zmodload zsh/langinfo
$ day=0
$ printf '%s\n' $langinfo[DAY_$((day+1))]
Sunday
```

Or:

```
$ zmodload zsh/datetime
$ day=0
$ TZ=UTC0 strftime %A $((86400 * (3+day)))
Sunday
```