# Why $argv got empty in zsh?

Tags: zsh

### file a

```
#!/bin/zsh
echo $*
echo $0

echo ---

echo $argv
echo $argv[0]
```

when the command is

```
./a 1 2
```

It shows:

```
1 2
./a
---

[0]
```

When the command is:

```
zsh ./a 1 2
```

It shows:

```
1 2
./a
---
1 2
```

Why the whether a 'zsh' being as an explict command can change the result ? And why argv[0] is not assigned?

Comment: For the first case, did you mean `bash ./a 1 2` or `sh ./a 1 2`?

Comment: For the first case, I did run the command `./a 1 2` in a zsh environment which is the same with the case 2. I don't know why the results are different. But I found if I try to `echo $-` in the script, the first is "hB" and the second is "569X", may be it's the reason. But I don't quite know why the option is so different between the two.

Comment: And what do you get if you run `/bin/zsh ./a 1 2`? Or `LC_ALL=C sed -n 'l;q' < a`?

Comment: The first command's result is the same with the Case 2. And the second command's output is "# x!/bin/zsh$"

Comment: So is it `# x!/bin/zsh` or `#!/bin/zsh`?

Comment: :D I get it thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$0` is not a positional parameter, it's not part of `$@`, it's the name of the script/function. `$*`, `$@` and `$argv` are all the same normal (non-sparse) array of the positional parameters and all array indices start at 1 in zsh unless you enable the `ksharrays` option.

But if you enable the `ksharrays` option for array indices to start at 0, you'll notice that `$argv[0]` or `${@[0]}` is the first positional parameter: `$1`.

Your confusion may be coming from arrays of ksh93-like shells (including `bash`), where `${@:0:1}` is `$0` even though the expansion of `"$@"` doesn't include `$0`. That confusion is the result of Korn choosing to make its shell array indices start at 0 even though the Bourne shell which it is based on, and most other shells and tools used by the shell chose to have their array indices start at 1.

More on that at [Is there a reason why the first element of a Zsh array is indexed by 1 instead of 0?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/252368)

Comment: Could you please tell me why in the second case, the value of the script name is not 
assigned to argv[0]?

Comment: As I said, because `$argv` contains the positional parameters (and the script name is not a positional parameter) and also because array indices start at 1, not 0, there can't be a value for indice 0.

Comment: Please look at http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/zsh_us.pdf  Page 12: exec part. Then, why after running command: `exec -a newargv0 zsh`,  it's still nothing but a newline as a output by `echo $argv[0]` .  So do you mean argv[0] will never be set, but $0 will? If so, why there is argv[0] in the document.

Comment: That document refers to the `char *argv[]` C language array that `zsh`'s `main()` routine receives, which is also the second argument to the `execve()` system call, not the `$argv[0]` of `zsh` language. See `man 2 execve`