# Using cat on array elements

Tags: bash, scripting, cat, array

Is it possible to cat array elements that are text files passed as input? I have something like this:

```
array=("$@")
cat array[3]
```

Where first I put all my arguments (some files.txt) into an array to handle them later and then for example I'd like to print the body of the third file (I know I could easily use `cat $3`).

Comment: It is possible, but you are dereferencing the array elements in a wrong way. The correct syntax is `cat "${array[3]}"`; have a look at [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) to prevent this kind of syntax errors in shell scripts. Addendum: numbering of array indices startes at 0 unless manually specified.

Comment: @AdminBee Yes you are right, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for accessing a particular element of an array is

```
${var[index]}
```

where `index` is an expression that evaluates to an integer between zero and the length of the array, minus 1 (array indexes in `bash` are zero-based).

To get `$3` from your array, use `${array[2]}`, i.e.

```
cat <"${array[2]}"
```

See also

- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)

You would use `array[3]` in an assignment:

```
array[3]=something
```

This would assign the string `something` to the fourth element in the array.

Also related to the fact that `bash` arrays start at zero:

- [Is there a reason why the first element of a Zsh array is indexed by 1 instead of 0?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252368/is-there-a-reason-why-the-first-element-of-a-zsh-array-is-indexed-by-1-instead-o)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried as you said but apparently it gives me the error "cat: ' ': File or directory does not exist" even though the file I'm passing to the script is inside that directory.

Comment: @Luca Your array contains a single space in that array element. You will have to show 1) your actual and complete code, including the invocation of the script, and 2) that the file is available. Please update your question. Also, the `cat` command usually says "No such file or directory". Did you translate the error message yourself?

Comment: ♦ No problem, solved it. I was simply cat-ing an empty array cell. Thank you.

Comment: In `bash` where arrays are sparse like in ksh which it tries to emulate, `array[3]=something` would only assign `something` to the "fourth" element if the elements of index 0, 1 and 2 were also set.